# Include any directory from tree to httpdocs folder

Tags: 12.04, apache2

Ubuntu 12.04, running on Apache server. 
Is possible to run/access from browser html/php file from other than document root location let's say from folder /testfolder on the root

So once I enter in browser example.com/testfolder It will be executed the same as from var/www/example.com/httpdocs/testfolder.

But files and this folder will be on the root in /testfolder not in document root (httpdocs) I don't want to put this folder physically at all in httpdocs. Goal is to hide those files/folder from default www vhost folder.

I don't want to change path but just put additional files which logically will exist in some other location on disk not default vhost document root folder.

I have tried with Alias and Directory but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html):

> The Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local
>   filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot.

Try to add this line inside `VirtualHost` definition:

```
Alias /testfolder /testfolder
<Directory /testfolder>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restart apache2 service.

If this doesn't work, check file and directory permission.